# Why does GCC not find my non-template function? ("no matching function for call to...")

Tags: gcc, templates, visual-c++

In MSVC 2008, I have the following code:

```
class Foo {
  //  Be a little smarter about deriving the vertex type, to save the user some typing.
  template<typename Vertex> inline void drawVertices(
    Elements vCount, RenPrim primitiveType, PixMaterial *mtl, Vertex const *vertices)
  {
    this->drawVertices(vCount, primitiveType, mtl, vertices, Vertex::VertexType);
  }

  virtual void drawVertices(
    Elements vCount,
    RenPrim primitiveType,
    PixMaterial *mtl,
    void const *vertices,
    uint vertexType) = 0;
};
```

I use it something like:

```
struct RenFlexibleVertexPc
{
  enum { VertexType = RenVbufVertexComponentsPc };
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
  GraVideoRgba8 c; // Video format, not external!
};


  PixMaterial *material;
  struct Pc : RenFlexibleVertexPc
          {
            void set(Triple t, uint cl) { x = (float)t.x_; y = (float)t.y_; z = (float)t.z_; c = cl; }
          } vpc[4];
  ...
  Foo *renderer;
  renderer->drawVertices(4, RenPrimTriangleFan, material, vpc);
```

This works fine in MSVC 2008 SP1. However, GCC (3.4 and 4.1,2) throws a "no matching function for call to function" error, apparently not seeing the template when there is a non-template function with more arguments.

Is GCC broken, or is my code broken, and if so, why?

Comment: indicate in your code where the compilation error happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with overloading or inheritance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

namespace {
    struct A {
        virtual void f()
        {
            std::cout<<"inside A's f()\n";
        }

        template <typename T> void f(T t)
        {
            std::cout<<T::i<<'\t';
            this->f();
        }
    };

    struct B : A {
        void f()
        {
            std::cout<<"hello\t";
            A::f();
        }
    };

    struct C {
        static const unsigned int i = 5;
    };

    struct D {
        enum { i = 6 };
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<A> b(new B());
    b->f(C());
    b->f(D());
}
```

Works correctly.  On the other hand, the smallest example I can find that exhibits your problem does not have inheritance or overloading:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    struct A {
        template<class C> void print(C c)
        {
            c.print();
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    struct B {
        void print()
        {
            std::cout << "whee!\n";
        }
    };

    A a;
    B b;
    a.print(b);
}
```

Note that if `struct B` is defined in a namespace (whether it's an unnamed namespace, or a completely different namespace, or the global namespace) instead of inside `main()` that this compiles without error.

<strike>I don't know enough of the standard to say if this is a bug, but it appears to be one.  I've gone ahead and [reported it to the GCC bug database](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39770).</strike>

---

And here's your answer from the GCC developers (from the link above):  "Local classes cannot be template arguments."

So the code is broken.  [Not that it's a bad idea](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1427.pdf).  In fact, C++0x removes this restriction.

I noticed the line

> Note that the code works in GCC if I explicitly cast vpc to (RenFlexibleVertexPc *)

And since `RenFlexibleVertexPc` is not a local class this makes sense.  However `Pc` is a local class/struct, so it is not allowed.

Comment: This was a great answer; thanks! Hope someone with reputation will vote it up.
I guess I'm just trying to live in the future...

Answer (score 1):

@OP: Specifying the template parameter is a valid approach.

```
renderer->drawVertices<RenFlexibleVertexPc>(4, RenPrimTriangleFan, material, vpc);
```

With Pete's additions, you code also compiles on Apple's GCC 4.0.1, so I suspect there's something your posted code is missing that's causing the problem.

@Max: GCC's treatment of your source is standard.  Struct B is local to main(), so B (and thus main()::B::print()) is not visible outside main().  As you're probably aware, moving the definition of B outside of main() and it will compile.

Comment: Thank you, I honestly did not know that.  However, you will notice that the original code sample (corrected so it will compile) struct Pc (i.e., the vpc[4] variable) is defined in the function, and moving that definition outside of the function resolves the problem -- leads to compiling code.

Comment: "Original code" as in line 12 of the original post's "I use it something like: ... struct Pc : RenFlexibleVertexPc { ... } vpc[4];"

Comment: That was what was missing in the OP's post.  I couldn't tell that the definition of struct Pc was local to the function (though the indentation should have been a hint).

Answer (score 0):

> The definition of `VertexType` is already in the code (an enum). Elements is an unsigned long. Note that the code works in GCC if I explicitly cast vpc to (`RenFlexibleVertexPc *`)

If it's an enum why pass an object of type array 4 of struct? What is `RenFlexibleVertexPc`? The last argument to `drawVertices` should either be a constant pointer to a `Vertex` object or a `const*` to an object of a class derived from `Vertex`.

```
Foo *renderer;
renderer->drawVertices(4, RenPrimTriangleFan, material, vpc);
```

You are calling a function on an uninitialized pointer. I hope this is not the real code. \

Comment: Of course it's not uninitialized in the real code. Note the "..." part.
The definition of VertexType is already in the code (an enum).
Elements is an unsigned long.
Note that the code works in GCC if I explicitly cast vpc to (RenFlexibleVertexPc *).

Comment: The '...' is before Foo *renderer;